# How to make raspberry donut filling

Tags: restaurant-mimicry, filling

How do I duplicate the raspberry flavored jelly filling of Dunkin Donuts jelly donuts?

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried other raspberry jelly fillings that weren't quite right, or is this your first attempt at a jelly filling ever?

Comment: Welcome! You might want to read [this Meta Q/A](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/what-are-restaurant-mimicry-questions) and consider to [edit] your question with more details. We do accept restaurant mimicry questions, but require a bit of effort from the asker.

Answer (score -1):

[Emeril's Raspberry Filling](https://emerils.com/120077/raspberry-filling) uses a combination of fresh raspberries, simple syrup, and cornstarch. Seems almost foolproof and you could probably substitute frozen raspberries when fresh aren't available.